# WebServicex Currency Convertor API

Tags: web-services, rest, http-post

WebServicex Currency Convertor API is returning always -1 as the conversion rate regardless of the currencies I specify..

Is there a way I can get it to work, to return an actual accurate conversion rate please?

I don't know why minus 1 is returned.  I think there are only 2 parameters FromCurrency and ToCurrency.  Here's an example URL I used:

HTTP POST REQUEST:

httppost://www.webservicex.net/currencyconvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency=GBP&ToCurrency=EUR

Here is what's returned:

-1

I also tried From USD to EUR but it still returned -1.

Do I need to register and enter a developer key as a parameter or something?  I didn't find that information anywhere, it's just a guess.

If nobody can help me with Webservicex; their service is not working properly; maybe it's just not a good one, can anybody recommend a good currency conversion web service.  I want to call the result from within my db solution to meet my clients request, and I only have a day before I need to show something working to them.  I hope you can help, it would be much appreciated.
Thankyou
Kind Regards
sharpie

Answer (score 0):

You may use the yahoo finance api.

http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=GBPEUR=X&f=l1

Although it will give the csv but if you will just use it in script then it will give you the direct transaction value.

I hope it will serve your purpose.

Comment: Thankyou Nlay that works really well.  It doesn't return csv or xml data with other values, so that I need to parse the conversion rate out, it just returns conversion rate alone, no parsing required. Nice.

Comment: Good to hear it helped you ! Cheers

Comment: Thankyou Nlay that works really well.  It doesn't return csv or xml data with other values, so that I need to parse the conversion rate out, it just returns conversion rate alone, no parsing required.Nice.
Is there a documentation / instruction page for that service that you can direct me to for future reference?as I couldn't find one.This is for in case they change something in future.Also for me to understand their URL in full and understand how I can manipulate the URL in my solution to control what it returns a bit more.i.e.what parts I need to change and what parts I need 2 leave

Comment: I hadn't finished typing the message first time and Stack overflow posted it :'(.  Please reply , and then I will accept your answer whatever your response is , if I can find how to do that ;)

Comment: Hey , I have used it in one of my old project 4/5 year ago and i couldn't find the documentation for the same. I have tried to check today as well but don't find any official documentation about the same. But i did found some GIT projects which you can look out .  https://github.com/scottjbarr/yahoo_currency

http://www.canbike.org/information-technology/yahoo-finance-url-download-to-a-csv-file.html

Comment: Hello Nlay.  So I see that the URL is specific for a conversion from GBP to EUR and doesn't work if I change those currencies to any other currency.  If there is a way to do that , then I don't know which specific parts to change because it's an unofficial web service and not supported by Yahoo from what I can work out.  Therefore there's no documentation for that.  I think I might just use the GBP to EUR conversion in my database app. That's what we get most commonly asked for. So how do I accept your answer? :)

Comment: I clicked the up arrow next to your answer to say it's useful.  Hopefully that's what you mean by accepting your answer :). I've just recently joined stackoverflow so not that familiar with it all.